# $this-referer() CakePHP 2 always returns home URL

Tags: cakephp

I've migrated a Cakephp 2 app from a server to a new one. 
Almost everything is working fine except some controllers with $this->referer() method.

Here is an example. I have a delete() method in NewsController, which redirects after deleting element :

```
$this->redirect($this->referer());
```

When I delete something, I have an error :

```
Error: [MissingActionException] Action NewsController::admin_www.website.org() could not be found.
```

Routing system try to redirect to the main url instead of last action. I tried to use this method :

```
$this->redirect( Router::url( $this->referer(), true ) );
```

Result is the same.

Here is the app folder structure :

```
/home/user/public_html/website.org/app/
```

and .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example of what `$this->referer()` is returning?

Comment: It returns the base url : www.website.org

Comment: If there's no `http://` in there, then it's no surprise the redirect breaks. It will see it as trying to redirect to `www.website.org` *relative to the current URL*. That is, if you're on `http://www.website.org/admin/whatever`, the redirect will be to `http://www.website.org/admin/www.website.org`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
I understand your point. But the unexpected part is that `$this->referer` should redirect to a specific action. The action is always www.website.org instead of the real one.

Comment: How does this compare to what `env('HTTP_REFERER')` returns?

Comment: `env('HTTP_REFERER')` returns null
`$this->referer()` returns www.website.org

Comment: The `referer` function appears to return `Configure::read('App.fullBaseUrl') . $this->webroot` in the case that the `HTTP_REFERER` is null. Are you setting `fullBaseUrl` in your config file? If so, have you neglected to include the required `http://` at the beginning of it?

Comment: `fullBaseUrl ` isn't set in the config file ? Maybe should I set it to exclude bad behaviors ?

Comment: Or look into how it does get set, to find out what's going wrong there?